# Python - Holding down key to move a sprite works, but only in one direction

Tags: 2d, python

I've been testing out movement for a fighting game that I'm creating in Python.

The problem is that when I try to move the sprite, it moves correctly to the left, but only ever works in that direction.
I think the problem is with my event handling loop, but I don't have much experience so I have no idea how to solve the problem. Googling and spending a while doing trial and error was no help.

My main loop looks like this:

```
pressedLeft = None
pressedRight = None
pressedUp = None
pressedDown = None

while True:

    #event handling
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                pressedLeft = True
            elif event.key == pygame.K_d:
                PressedRight = True
            elif event.key == pygame.K_w:
                PressedUp = True
            elif event.key == pygame.K_s:
                PressedDown = True
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                pressedLeft = False
            elif event.key == pygame.K_d:
                PressedRight = False
            elif event.key == pygame.K_w:
                PressedUp = False
            elif event.key == pygame.K_s:
                PressedDown = False

    # movement
    if pressedLeft:
        profx -= 5
    elif pressedRight:
        profx += 5
    elif pressedUp:
        profy -= 5
    elif pressedDown:
        profy += 5
    DisplaySurf.fill(white)
    DisplaySurf.blit(profImg, (profx, profy))
    pygame.display.update()
    fpsClock.tick(FPS)
```

Comment: You have an issue with the capitalization of your variable names. You use a lowercase first letter for `pressedLeft`, but you're not careful with the other names (`PressedRight` vs `pressedRight`, same for `up` and  `down`).

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt wanna make an answer out of that? I don't wanna steal yours :)

Comment: @KevinvanderVelden This is almost too trivial for an answer, but oh well!

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt Agreed, but it keeps the unanswered list down :)

Answer (score 5):

You have an issue with the capitalization of your variable names.

You use a lowercase first letter for `pressedLeft`, but you're not careful with the other names (`PressedRight` vs `pressedRight`, same for up and down).

This results in the creation of never used values in your `if` blocs.

The syntax colouring helped my spot it right away.

This should do the trick:

```
pressedLeft = None
pressedRight = None
pressedUp = None
pressedDown = None

while True:

    #event handling
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                pressedLeft = True
            elif event.key == pygame.K_d:
                pressedRight = True
            elif event.key == pygame.K_w:
                pressedUp = True
            elif event.key == pygame.K_s:
                pressedDown = True
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                pressedLeft = False
            elif event.key == pygame.K_d:
                pressedRight = False
            elif event.key == pygame.K_w:
                pressedUp = False
            elif event.key == pygame.K_s:
                pressedDown = False

    # movement
    if pressedLeft:
        profx -= 5
    elif pressedRight:
        profx += 5
    elif pressedUp:
        profy -= 5
    elif pressedDown:
        profy += 5
    DisplaySurf.fill(white)
    DisplaySurf.blit(profImg, (profx, profy))
    pygame.display.update()
    fpsClock.tick(FPS)
```